# Existe alguna forma más eficiente de aplicar un método a todos los elementos de una lista que por un ciclo en Python

Tags: python

Me pregunto si existe una forma más eficiente de aplicarle el mismo método a todos los elementos de una lista que la siguiente:

```
fecha = [int(i) for i in ('06', '12', '2020')]
```

Gracias

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema con el código que muestras? ¿En que te basas para sugerir que existe otro código *más* eficiente?

Comment: Primero deberías definir eficiencia. Una sintaxis alternativa es usar `map()`, que en tu caso sería `fecha = map(int, ('06', '12', '2020' ))`. Es ligeramente más corta. También ligeramente más difícil de leer. Y también ligeramente más lenta. Creo que en todos los sentidos sería más eficiente la forma de list comprehension que tú has usado, salvo en el número de caracteres usados. Como no se trate de un concurso de código ultracorto, yo no usaría `map()`.

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que `map()` es más lenta? De hecho me parecería lo contrario, ya que `map()` devuelve un iterator que efectúa de manera lazy (on-demand) la operación. Por el contrario, la comprehensión de lista evalúa y carga en memoria el resultado de la operación de una vez. @abulafia

Comment: Es más, para iterables muy largos yo usaría `map()` por la razón que acabo de mencionar. @abulafia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependiendo de la dimensión del iterable de entrada (que en este caso es la tupla `('06', '12', '2020')`), pudieses considerar usar [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) en lugar de una comprehensión de lista, **siempre y cuando** no necesites mantener los elementos del iterable de salida (`fecha`) en memoria (por ejemplo, si no necesitas acceder a elementos usando índices, algo como `fecha[x]`).

Esto es debido a que la función builtin `map()` devuelve un iterador que efectúa la operación (en este caso, crear enteros a partir de strings) únicamente cuando así es requerido, y no almacena en memoria el resultado.

Por lo tanto, si el iterable de entrada es grande, y dependiendo de tu caso de uso, usando `map()` puedes tener una ejecución más eficiente de tu programa al momento de crear el iterable de salida `fecha`.

Para ilustrar esto, veamos este ejemplo:

```py
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> import random
>>> x = random.choices(['01', '12', '423', '4', '7'], k=1_000_000)
>>> timeit('fecha = map(int, x)', globals={'x': x}, number=1)
5.584999598795548e-06
>>> timeit('fecha = [int(i) for i in x]', globals={'x': x}, number=1)
0.12524279300123453
```

Siendo `x` una lista de un millón de elementos, el tiempo que toma crear el objeto `fecha` usando `map()`, es, lógicamente, gigantescamente (~2,24×10¹² veces) menor. Además, teniendo el plus de que en memoria no existe esa lista con un millón de elementos.

Desde luego, si tu caso de uso es el de iterar sobre `fecha` luego, el uso de `map()` sigue siendo más eficiente (~1,54 veces más rápido). Veamos el siguiente ejemplo:

```
>>> x = random.choices(['01', '12', '423', '4', '7'], k=1000000)
>>> def speed_test_map(x):
    fechas = map(int, x)
    for fecha in fechas:
        fecha += 1


>>> def speed_test_list_comprehension(x):
    fechas = [int(i) for i in x]
    for fecha in fechas:
        fecha += 1


>>> timeit('func(x)', globals={'x': x, 'func': speed_test_map}, number=1)
0.11742365100144525
>>> timeit('func(x)', globals={'x': x, 'func': speed_test_list_comprehension}, number=1)
0.18061448600019503
```